# How to loop over posts in Hexo with native Jade construction

Tags: node.js, pug

I know, that I can use something like this:

```
- site.posts.each(function(article){
      h2.title= article.title
      p.article= arcticle.content
- })
```

I feel this way wrong, because Jade has its own native construction for looping over something, but it seems not working:

```
each article in site.posts
     h2.title= article.title
     p.article= arcticle.content
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details why do you think that the second code snippet does not work?

Comment: I don't why know it doesn't work. All I have is that I see result with first snippet and see that article is not defined with second. I suppose that site.post returns data structures not fully compatible with native jade loop, but I have no ideas how to handle this.

Comment: `each article in array` is correct statement. If Jade would not be able to _handle_, it would probably throw an error. Can you check if `site.posts` is an array in your request handler, say, using `util.isArray(site.posts)`. Alternatively print content of site object into console (`util.inspect(site, { showHidden: true, depth: 3 })`) and check if `posts` is printed as an array (`[]`)

Comment: Posts is NOT an array, but some weird dictionary object with `_index` and `_populates` keys... This is just... strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do `site.posts.toArray()` and the loop will work fine. This had me confused for a while too and the answer on github is mostly in Chinese.

https://github.com/tommy351/hexo/issues/321